# How can I use the devise user_signed_in? method in an integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I have `assert user_signed_in?` in an integration test it says the method is undefined.  Is there a way I can use this method in my testing?  I am using rails 4 and the latest version of devise.  Here is my test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

test "valid signup information" do
    get new_user_registration_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect user_registration_path, 
                                     user: { first_name: "Example",
                                             last_name:  "User",
                                             email:      "user@example.org",
                                             password:              "password",
                                             password_confirmation: "password" }
    end
    assert_template 'activities/index'
    assert user_signed_in?
  end
```

Comment: We'll need more than that. Please read the advice on how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry about that, fixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `user_signed_in?` method is included in `Devise::Controllers::Helpers` module which isn't available in your integration tests so you can't use it.

You have the option of either mocking this method (which won't really meet your testing needs) or testing that a user is signed in by looking for page content that will only render when the user is signed in like `Logout` link for example or `Signed in successfully` message.

For your controller tests you can use devise test helpers `include Devise::TestHelpers` which exposes a `sign_in` and `sign_out` methods for you, more on that in the Gem's home page https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `user_signed_in?` inside integration tests as mentioned here before me, but you can write a simple helper method to help you mimic this behavior

what i did is ,inside the test_helper.rb :

```
 def is_logged_in?
  request.env['warden'].authenticated?(:user)
 end
```

it's a pretty hacky solution but it does the trick